# Prevent debug log on compile in VS08

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I'm trying to make it so that when I compile my code(in any configuration) in VS08, it doesn't automatically switch my output window from "Build" to "Debug". I'm not trying to prevent it from logging anything, Its a cosmetic change if anything. I'm just tired of switching back all the time. ( I do so because I use the build output with message pragmas for some things.)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so sure why you have this problem.  Try to build with Ctrl+Shift+B instead of F5.  The F5 keystroke starts the debugger.  And triggers a rebuild if your code changed.  And switches the Output window mode from "Build" to "Debug" when the debugger starts.

The other important setting is Tools + Options, Project and Solution, Build and Run, "On Run, when a build or deployment error occur".  Keep that at "Do not launch".  Not sure what they were smoking when they made that an option.

Comment: Thank you very much! The Ctrl+Shift+B thing works. I had been using the green arrow with release configuration. I didn't know that also launched the debugging even in release.